# Twisted Reactor for client-side python interface / raw_input

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am using twisted to run a rather complicated server that allows for data collection, communication, and commanding of a hardware device remotely. On the client-side there are a number of data retrieval and command operations available. Typically I use the wxpython reactor to interface with the client reactor, but I would also like to setup a simpler command-line style interface.

Is there a reactor that I can use to setup a local non-blocking python-like or `raw_input`-style interface for the client? After successful access to the server, the server will occasionally send data down without being requested as a result of server-side events.

I have considered `manhole`, but I am not interested in accessing the server as an interface, I am strictly interested in accessing the client-side data and commands. This is mostly for debugging, but it can also come in handy for creating a much more rudimentary client interface when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `stdin.py` and `stdiodemo.py` [examples](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/), I think that's similar to what you're aiming for. They demonstrate connecting a protocol (like a `LineReceiver`) to [StandardIO](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO.html).

I think you could also use a [StandardIOEndpoint](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.StandardIOEndpoint.html) (and maybe we should update the examples for that), but that doesn't change the way you'd write your protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in this direction, I think this should do what I needed.